# Hoisting and 'let' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

Question is:

why doesn't this throw a reference error:

```
console.log(a)
let a = 5;
```

but this throws a reference error:

```
{
 console.log(a)
 let a = 5;
}
```

Now, if we use 'var' then in both cases the code will run and log out 'undefined', but can someone explain what's happening with 'let' (and 'const').

Comment: Both throw a reference error.

Comment: I tried the first code in Node and Chrome's console, and both threw a "ReferenceError"

Comment: I can't reproduce your described behavior.  Are you sure you don't already have a definition of `a` in scope, from before the test code you're showing?

Comment: @mark even then it will throw.

Comment: Mind what you are writing: your two chunks of code are strictly identical. Now, what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, both of these throw a reference error.

```js
console.log(a)
let a = 5;
```

```js
{
 console.log(a)
 let a = 5;
}
```

But you are correct. If you use `var` then `undefined` is logged to the console.

```js
console.log(a)
var a = 5;
```

From a [blog post on medium](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-variable-hoisting-differentiating-between-var-let-and-const-in-es6-f1a70bb43d) - which isn't by me - where you can read more about it.

> The JavaScript engine treats all variable declarations using “var” as
>   if they are declared at the top of a functional scope(if declared
>   inside a function) or global scope(if declared outside of a function)
>   regardless of where the actual declaration occurs. This essentially is
>   “hoisting”.

This only applies to `var`. `let` and `const` will throw reference errors and is well documented (see [ECMAScript 2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations)). This is because although `let` and `const` are hoisted they are not initialised until the code executes the initialising line. The time between a `let` or `const` being hoisted and initialised is commonly know as the *temporal dead zone*.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, which is perfectly correct, although useless: the question itself reveals a basic unwillingness to refer to the available documentation.